# Getting size in bytes of a zarr group

Tags: python, zarr

How can I get the size of a zarr group in bytes?

Comment: Do you now how to get the size of a zarr group in any other unit?

Comment: Do you want to know the compressed or the uncompressed size?

Answer (score 1):

```
import zarr

# Open your Zarr group
group = zarr.open_group('path_to_your_zarr_group', mode='r')

# Get the size of the group in bytes
size_in_bytes = zarr.getsize(group)

print(f"Size of Zarr group: {size_in_bytes} bytes")
```

Replace `path_to_your_zarr_group` with the actual path to your Zarr group file or directory. This code will open the group in read-only mode and then retrieve its size in bytes using `zarr.getsize()`.